# Macos terminal - Find and mark latest PDF in a folder

Tags: bash, terminal, automator

I am looking for a solution that will help me find the latest PDF file in specified folder and mark them with the GREEN tag as the latest. Anyone have an idea how to do it?
So far I only found the terminal/bash command to print the latest PDF file.
echo -n "newest file: $ (ls -t * .pdf | head -n1)
It can also be Automator workflow.
Can anyone help?

I'm using MacOS High Sierra

Comment: warning no space between * and .pdf: `ls -t *.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer in superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/168927/mac-os-x-how-to-change-the-color-label-of-files-from-the-terminal), you can do it like this:

```
osascript - 6 $ (ls -t *.pdf | head -n1) << EOF
on run argv
    set labelIndex to (item 1 of argv as number)
    repeat with i from 2 to (count of argv)
      tell application "Finder"
          set theFile to POSIX file (item i of argv) as alias
          set label index of theFile to labelIndex
      end tell
    end repeat
end run
EOF
```

There are some obvious optimizations, like removing the loop or just using the function as defined in the superuser answer.